# Photoshop CC 2014 - Selecting a pixel art isometric line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, pixel-art, isometric

Is there a quick way to select an entire pixel art isometric line (i.e. 2 pixels across for every 1 down, [see here for example](https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/358/posts/21825/image/05-volumes-io.png)).

Thanks

Comment: As a raster element, no. It's not a line in that situation, but just a bunch of pixels. However, with judicious use of layers, you can separate things out to make them easier to select.

Answer (score 1):

Click with *magic wand* tool and select similar